# Cannot compile .cpp in vscode terminal

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, terminal

When i try to run my .cpp program in bash terminal in vscode, I receive this response(when I fisrstly compile --> then run from terminal, it runs without issues):

```
junte@anton MINGW64 /c/cpp_code
$ cd "C:\cpp_code\"
> cd "c:\cpp_code\" && g++ helloworld.cpp -o helloworld && "c:\cpp_code\"helloworld
>
```

The "Run in terminal" is on and compiler is in PATH.
I'm curoius where is the issue and how to fix it

Here is my tasks.json :

```
{
"tasks": [
    {
        "type": "cppbuild",
        "label": "C/C++: g++.exe сборка активного файла",
        "command": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe",
        "args": [
            "-g",
            "${file}",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        },
        "detail": "Задача создана отладчиком."
    }
],
"version": "2.0.0"
}
```

And launch.json :

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "g++.exe - Сборка и отладка активного файла",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": false,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gdb.exe",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Включить автоматическое форматирование для gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ],
        "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++.exe сборка активного файла"
    }
]
```

P.S thanks for any help<3

Comment: Since you use `bash`, switch to forward slashes instead of backslashes in your paths. Backslash starts an escape sequence in `bash` - it's not a directory separator.

Comment: I've tried to and the only thing happened is backward slashes became forward in my response in terminal